# Configure Hazelcast via external yml-file

Tags: java, dockerfile, hazelcast

I´ve a running hzc-yml configuration in classpath - the generated jar file works fine in a docker context. Now I want to load this yml-file externally. I added this startup-property to my DOCKERFILE:

```
-Dhazelcast.config=`./hazelcast.yaml`
```

The whole DOCKERFILE looks like:

```
FROM openjdk:14
VOLUME /tmp
WORKDIR /service
RUN mkdir /service/logs
COPY jar/hazelcast.yaml hazelcast.yaml
COPY jar/log4j.properties log4j.properties
COPY jar/hzc-service.jar hzc-service.jar
ENTRYPOINT exec java \
-Dhazelcast.config=`./hazelcast.yaml` \
-Dhazelcast.logging.type=log4j \
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:./log4j.properties \
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom \
--add-modules java.se --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED \
$JAVA_OPTS \
-jar hzc-service.jar
```

It seems that the service wants to apply the external yml-file, but I always get this error:

hzc-service  | /bin/sh: ./hazelcast.yaml: Permission denied

I applied "chmod 777" to the file with no effect.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
 -Dhazelcast.config=`./hazelcast.yaml`
```

Just remove the backticks and put the filename between quotes:

```
 -Dhazelcast.config='./hazelcast.yaml'
```

With the backtick character, you open a subshell in bash, and try to run the hazelcast.yaml in it (which of course doesn't make sense).